# How to set margins to autocompletetextview adapter

Tags: android, baseadapter, autocompletetextview

I have and `autocompletetextview` set inside a toolbar. when user provides search query i have an adapter(with some dummy data added for testing) that shows the results based on search query.

The problem is with adapter width as it is set to `autocompletetextview` width.
But here i want the adapter width to set to toolbar width and a margin between toolbar and adapter.

This is the code i have written:

```
searchView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
SearchAdapter searchAdapter = new SearchAdapter(NavigationDrawerActivity.this,searchResults,searchView);
        searchView.setAdapter(searchAdapter);
```

Here is my adapter:

```
public class SearchAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SearchResult> {

    private boolean mAnimate;
    private AutoCompleteTextView mSearch;
    public SearchAdapter(Context context, List<SearchResult> options, AutoCompleteTextView search) {
        super(context, 0, options);
        mSearch = search;
    }

    int count = 0;

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        SearchResult option = getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.search_option, parent, false);

         /*   if (true) {
                Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),
                        R.anim.anim_down);
                anim.setDuration(400);
                convertView.startAnimation(anim);
                if (count == this.getCount()) {
                    mAnimate = false;
                }
                count++;
            }*/
        }

        View border = convertView.findViewById(R.id.border);
        if (position == 0) {
            border.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            border.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        final TextView title = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText(option.title);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        icon.setImageDrawable(option.icon);
        ImageView up = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.up);
        up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mSearch.setText(title.getText().toString());
                mSearch.setSelection(mSearch.getText().length());
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Here is my adapter row layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:cropToPadding="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#212121"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="62dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/up"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/up"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|right"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_up" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/border"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#E8E8E8" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

With the above code i am getting like this:
[Need the adapter aligned to toolbar width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1r5d.png)
I have tried setting adapter width like this:

```
 Rect screenSize = new Rect();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRectSize(screenSize);
        // screen width
        int screenWidth = screenSize.width();
        int adapterMargin = (int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.adapter_margin);
        searchView.setDropDownWidth(screenWidth - adapterMargin);
```

But the problem here is i'm getting not getting right margin as shown below:
[screen with adapter width set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYVEF.png)

Please help me on how to tackle this problem.

Comment: Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you want to set adapter width to be set to toolbar width add the following line to your code it will work:

```
searchView.setDropDownAnchor(toolbar.getId());
```

Comment below if you have any further doubts

Comment: Can you tell on how to give top padding for adapter so that it will stay below the toolbar

Answer (score 0):

Modify this line

```
searchView.setDropDownWidth(screenWidth - adapterMargin);
```

to the following, may be this will change.

```
searchView.setDropDownWidth(screenWidth - adapterMargin * 2);
```

Comment: Yes i have tried the same but it is giving the width only from left, sorry i forgot to mention this in my question.